# How to generate the code coverage report using jacoco where source code and tests are in different projects?

Tags: maven, testng, code-coverage, pom.xml, jacoco

I have a maven java project in some folder (it has some unit tests), and tests for the same code in another different project (different directory). Both source code and test share the same parent pom. Now I want to generate the code coverage report using JaCoCo.

How to instrument sources? How to run tests on instrumented code? And how to integrate and get the result report?

Say Project ABC contains the code and project XYZ contains the test cases.
Note:

1. Project ABC and Project XYZ are independent projects
2. Both ABC and XYZ contains multiple sub projects(Need to integrate everything).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I found a solution by changing the path of the jacoco report path:

```
<sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${project.basedir}/../target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
```

I added these properties and configured the jacoco plugin to append reports and not overwrite them by:

```
<configuration>
<append>true</append>
</configuration>
```

This way jacoco write the reports to the base directory of the multi module project. The sonar plugin finds these and analyses them.

Comment: Please give me more details.

Comment: More details about what?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem when building a "reference application" with multiple sub-modules and trying to generate test coverage for the sub-modules and have them push to sonarqube. The issue I was having was that since the sub-modules referenced each other, the resulting jacoco reports were getting overwritten and I'd end up with results for a single module. This may not be the same issue as posted above, but I did solve it by using "append" in gradle, so just want to show how to do that.

In the build.gradle file for each module, I have:

```html
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                append = true
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
            systemProperty 'robolectric.enabledSdks', '28'
        }
    }
```

s